# Salesforce integration with Genesys and Avaya

Tags: cti, call-center

Is it possible to integrate 2 Different CTI from one salesforce instance. for eg:

Salesforce to  avaya and genesys.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: If you can provide a bit more information about why you need to do this it would help - see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create multiple Call Centers (one for each CTI adapter) within Salesforce and assign them to different users.

For further information see the Salesforce help site for [Creating a Call Center](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cti_admin_createcc.htm&language=en_US) and [Managing Call Center Users](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=cti_admin_manageagents.htm&siteLang=en_US)